# Equação de 1° grau em C

Tags: c, matemática

Como eu posso implementar um **algoritmo** que calcule uma equação de **1° grau** em **C**?

Eu sei que uma equação de primeiro grau para ser solucionada deve-se seguir três passos:

> 1°: Agrupar os números de um lado do **=** todos os termos que tenham
>   a incógnita (x) e junte no outro lado todos os termos que não têm
>   (**x**). Para fazer esta transposição, os sinais que vão à frente de
>   cada numero devem ser mudados. Assim, o que está a somar de um lado
>   passa para o outro a subtrair e vice-versa, e o que está a multiplicar
>   de um lado passa para o outro a dividir.
>
> Exemplo: **4x + 1= 2x + 7**
>
> Transposição: **4x - 2x = 7 - 1**
>
> 2°: Resolver as operações de forma separada de cada lado do sinal de
>   igual. Ou seja, para resolver a equação de primeiro grau deve resolver
>   as operações até deixar um número de cada lado do igual.
>
> Resultado: **2x = 6**
>
> 3°: Finalmente, para resolver a equação de primeiro grau o número que
>   esta a multiplicar pelo x passa a dividir para o outro lado do sinal
>   de igual, no nosso caso:
>
> **x = 6 / 2**
>
> Resultado final: **x = 3**

Implementação seguida da resposta do @Rafael Carneiro de Moraes:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    float x, a, b, c;

    b = 1 + 7;

    a = 4 + 2;

    c = a + b;

    x = (c - b) / a;

    printf("\nx = %f",x);

    return 0;
}
```

Não sei se o resultado esta correto.

Comment: O que você já fez?

Comment: Estou tentando implementar o exemplo acima, mais não estou conseguindo definir uma logica de como representar esses passos em programação.

Comment: Você não precisa declarar `c` como `a + b` porque o resultado vai dar errado. Vou usar o seu exemplo (*4x + 1= 2x + 7*): juntando os lados iguais ficaria *2x = 6* e o valor do seu *x* deve ser 3. Ou seja, nesse caso você deve fazer:

`b = 1; 
a = 4 - 2;
c = 7;
x = (c - b) / a;`

Comment: Implementei aqui, o resultado deu 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Levando em conta uma equação do tipo *ax + b = c*, sendo:

- *ax*: a soma de todos os x da equação
- *b*: a soma de todos os números da equação
- *c*: o resultado

E supondo que seu program vai receber os valores de `a`, `b` e `c`, a equação que você precisa para é `x = (c - b) / a`.

Se você tem mais de um *x* você precisa fazer testes `if`/`else` para calcular `a`, pois se ele for 0 não há equação e sim uma possível igualdade de *b* e *c*.